# Recommended Tour Operator for 'Golden Triangle' India

Tags: india, tours, new-delhi

I'm planning on visiting India in November/December. I'd like to spend 4 days doing the 'Golden Triangle' - Delhi/Agra/Jaipur.

I'm looking to do this on a cheap budget i.e. back packer style. I'm just interested in seeing the sights - not looking for luxury.

There seems to be lots of tour operators for this itinerary. Can anyone recommend one?

Or would it be recommended to simply use trains/taxis and book accommodation myself? I prefer the idea of a tour because it would potentially be less stressful to organise and also means I'd probably meet like minded travelers.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, this question is too broad - there is no criteria listed and there are dozens of tour operators in the region. Unless you have very specific tour requirements, this question is too broad for this site.

Comment: Ok, well you're the boss. Personally I think its a perfectly reasonable question. As you say, there are dozens of tour operators in the region; therein lies my dilemma - which one do I go with? I thought perhaps other users who have done this popular tour may have been able to share their experience and recommendations.

Comment: @DavidMasters If you provide some criteria, e.g. a price range, etc. so that we can provide an answer, this could be reopened, imho.$

Comment: @RoflcoptrException OK done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet would the Rajasthan State Government owned-operated [tourism development corporation](http://www.rajasthantourism.gov.in/.).  They have their own buses, hotels, and tour packages, so you get kind of an end to end solution.

Private tour operators coordinate with different agencies and sometimes their plans go wrong.  When that happens there is nothing you can do really other than grin and bear it.

RTDC is more organized and responsive.

You may also try [Delhi Tourism](http://www.delhitourism.gov.in/) again a government undertaking.

The lesson being stick with the government.  They may lack the glamour, but they are well organized.

I am not associated with RTDC or Delhi Tourism, though I am an Indian.

Comment: When I looked at Delhi Tourism they were much cheaper than all of the private operators I was seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a tour operator if you want to save money. Just use the transport department buses to get to your destinations and do your own thing. [Here](http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/itinerary-help-with-5-days-trip-in-jaipur.254/#post-685) is a post that describes how to do it. The only thing you need to change is the mode of transport which in that post is a taxi. Check out a few tour operators and find out what all they cover and make a list. Use public transport to get there and back. Public transport in India is one of the cheapest in the world especially trains which are subsidized by the government to a great extent.

I hope this helps.